# How to Add RESTful Web Services to Joomla 1.5+

Tags: api, rest, joomla, joomla1.5

pretty straightforward question:

1. Is there a good web services solution for Joomla1.5+? I've been searching all over, and have only found references to a poorly-documented new xml-rpc server that's built into Joomla: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=304&t=501897

Thanks a lot - I'm looking for a nice clean third-party app for this!

J

Comment: Hi, I'm really interested in REST for joomla but all the answers for you and all the results I found after hours of searching are for Joomla 1.5 and I can find nothing for Joomla 2.5+. Do you know something that can be used for this version and above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that xmlrpc is being deprecated in joomla 1.6

You might want to try this:

http://github.com/plexicloud/Plexicloud-JWS

Comment: Thank you Andy!  Also, I've found a few "Future" solutions that seem like they will be well-integrated with Joomla 1.5 / 1.6+: Nooku (www.nooku.org) develops some API frameworks to power other Extensions/Aps.  Also, JomSocial (www.jomsocial.com) has in their 2010 RoadMap to add REST-based API services - AWESOME!

Comment: I tried to install Plexiclould-JWS as described here https://github.com/plexicloud/Plexicloud-JWS/wiki
But I could not access any of the API urls, for example http://servername.com/api/index.php?method=requestAPIKey&userid=63
returns not found, Am I missing something?

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for resurrecting an old post
https://github.com/techjoomla/Joomla-REST-API is also a good option

We're using that one for a few production sites

Comment: Thanks Ashwin - that was a very helpful link!

Comment: Hi ...I used this link...it installed successfully...but cant find an option to use it...plz help

Comment: This is the updated repo https://github.com/techjoomla/com_api

Answer (score 0):

we've portet some older code for 1.5,1.6,1.7,2.57 and soon 3.1. Its XML-RPC but its easy to ouput JSON. http://www.xapp-studio.com/web/xapp-studio/downloads. Please have a look again in a few weeks, we're adopting this to JSON right now too.