# webservices to access joomla website

Tags: android, mysql, joomla

I want to write an app which can be installed on iphone or Android and communicate the website with Joomla installed on it. I understand that Joomla is a CMS to handle front end and database.
My question is, for the iphone app to communicate the website database, do I have to write plugins for Joomla, or do I have to create a seperate engine which communicated database directly? 
Thanks.

Comment: this post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417186/how-to-add-restful-web-services-to-joomla-1-5

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Joomla API](http://docs.joomla.org/API) or you can implement whatever you want with PHP code that you'll build yourself, which is actually creating your own "API". for example, you can write a php that will be hosted on the same server as Joomla which will call the DB and list the names and emails of all the users (from jos_users) - this is pretty easy to implement on the server's side, and you can implement a call to this PHP on the client side (phone) which will send a request and parse the response and display it.